# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define LSevenZip/CRC

Tags: android, compiler-errors

my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.varuniyer.contetto"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('/Users/varuniyer/AndroidStudioProjects/Contetto/xwalk_core_library/libs/xwalk_core_library.jar')
    compile files('/Users/varuniyer/AndroidStudioProjects/Contetto/xwalk_shared_library/libs/xwalk_shared_library.jar')
}
```

I'm trying to create a Crosswalk Android example application.

I keep getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define LSevenZip/CRC;
```

I've looked at other questions but none of their solutions have worked. I'm kinda stuck what to do now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try just pulling in just the core library i.e. removing the following line from the build:

compile files('/Users/varuniyer/AndroidStudioProjects/Contetto/xwalk_shared_library/libs/xwalk_shared_library.jar')

Worth checking out this link too:
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/shared_mode.html